# Optimize integer division

Tags: integers

I have two positive integers $x$ and $y$.

I need to calculate $\frac{100x}{x+y}$ and $\frac{100y}{x+y}$, which sum up to $100$ of course.

However, I can only perform integer division.

And since the results still need to sum up to $100$, I calculate one of them, and then calculate the other via "$1000$ minus the previous".

I'd like to know which one to choose such that the outcome will be as accurate as possible.

One problem that arises is how to even define *accurate* here (i.e., how to measure the accuracy of the outcome).

So let's define the accuracy as $p(x,y)=|\frac{x}{y}-\frac{x'}{y'}|$, where $x'$ and $y'$ are the two outcomes.

The smaller $p(x,y)$ is, the more accurate is the result of my computation.

So my question is, how exactly should I choose between these two options:

- Calculate $x'=\left\lfloor\frac{100x}{x+y}\right\rfloor$ and then $y'=100-x'$
- Calculate $y'=\left\lfloor\frac{100y}{x+y}\right\rfloor$ and then $x'=100-y'$

My initial though is to always choose the larger value first (i.e., calculate $a=\left\lfloor\frac{100\max(x,y)}{x+y}\right\rfloor$ and then $b=100-a$), because "less information" will be lost.

Couldn't find any counterexamples of that, so does anyone here happen to know a formal proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand everything correctly, the conjecture is false. Sometimes the smaller value is better.

Example case: x = 1, y=2.

If we do the division with the larger value, y, then we get

$$y' = \lfloor \frac {200} 3 \rfloor = 66, x' = 100-y' = 34$$

The true ratio is $\frac 1 2,$ so our error is $|\frac 1 2 - \frac {34} {66} | = \frac 1 {66}.$

Compare with doing the division with the smaller value, $x,$ so we get

$$x' = \lfloor \frac {100} 3 \rfloor = 33, y' = 100-x' = 67$$

which gives an error of $|\frac 1 2 - \frac{33}{67}| = \frac 1 {134}.$ Smaller than doing the larger division!

If you graph the error function with fixed $x$ or $y$ and a particular method, it's really quite chaotic. For example, if $y=10$ then computing $y'$ is better for $x \in \{2, 4 \}$ while $x'$ is better for $x \in \{1, 3, 5,6,7,8,9 \}.$

Comment: Thank you very much. Good catch! That kinda answers one half of my question, since I'd still like to know of a method to choose the better option (of the two). So I'll wait a little more for some other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

For an example of integer division

800 / 11 = 72 r8

80 / 11 = 7 r3

30 / 11 = 2 r8

80 / 11 = 7 r3

for 72.727 as 72.73

and

300 / 11 = 27 r3

30 / 11 = 2 r8

80 / 11 = 7 r3

30 / 11 = 2 r8

for 27.272 as 27.27  .